# Attempting to build template but Having Issue with gets and posts

Tags: php, template

I am building my first real php web app. as many you know this requires building LOTS of pages.

in attempting to streamline the repetitive stuff i placed most of my stuff within a content.php page which looks like this

```
?php include_once ('config3.inc');?>
<?php if(isset($_GET['p'])){
    $page = $_GET['p'];

}else {
    $page ='';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en">

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title><?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?></title>
    <?php include('styles.inc');?>

   <?php include('api.inc'); ?>
   <?php include('scripts.inc');?>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <?php include ('header.inc');?>

    <div><!-- Content -->
    <?php include  ('./content/'.$page);?>
    </div>

</div><!-- end container -->
<!-- Footer -->
<?php include ('footer.inc');?>
</body>
</html>
```

This way when I want to call up a page I go to `www.domain.com/content.php?p=pagename.php` and it will "wrap" everything in the correct style sheets container and footer etc.

had been working well until I started making my CRUD pages requiring that pagename use `POST` data.

Is there a better approach for this or do I need to scrap this approach entirely?

Comment: Why is this off-topic? this is working code...

Comment: I don't work with php at all, but doing an include a php page received in a parameter look not safe at all to me.

Comment: Marc-Andre I agree it would be unwise to include a file based solely upon a parameter my structure is passing it to a subfolder within my structure to prevent external includes. however i am taking a look at using some existing frameworks moving forward on this project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more elegant approach would be to adopt the MVC pattern as a foundational framework. I suggest using [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) because it is well-documented and accessible for those who are generally new to MVC. The current method of coding incorporates too much business logic, which, in the long term, leads to unmanageability.

To avoid this, the MVC pattern offers a clear and maintainable coding strategy. I recommend starting with an informative article from Nettuts, titled [MVC for Noobs](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/mvc-for-noobs/). Despite the title, the article is quite insightful and provides a basic understanding of the MVC pattern.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Also look into TWIG. the template engine of symfony

Comment: ` because the code becomes maintainable ` I think you wanted to say not maintainable ;)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, i will be looking into some frameworks.

Comment: Wow!, just came across this old post after now having been using Laravel for 8+years. @kreshnik thanks for the suggestion.